# "Python Pandas - Merging DataFrames with Different Column Names"

Tags: mysql, pandas

"I'm currently working on a data analysis project using Python's Pandas library, and I'm facing an issue with merging two DataFrames that have different column names. I've tried using the merge() function, but I'm encountering difficulties due to the disparate column names in the DataFrames.

One DataFrame contains 'employee_id' and 'salary', while the other contains 'emp_id' and 'income'. How can I merge these DataFrames based on the 'employee_id' and 'emp_id' columns, while handling the differing column names?

I've attempted renaming the columns and using the merge() function with various parameters, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result. Any guidance or examples on how to effectively merge the DataFrames considering the varying column names would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your question have to do with `Digital Signature Algorithm` (`dsa`)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
df3 = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on='employee_id', right_on='emp_id', how='left')
```

As you did not post sample of your data I had to guess the name of your dataframe and name of columns in each.
Also you can play with the different options for 'how'.

For full syntex of `pandas.merge`, click [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html).